# Function to copy rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table as bellow in Excel and I would like to copy rows 3, 7, 11, 15, 19,...on the left to the right as in the picture.
Is there a function to do this?
Thank you for help.[image]

Comment: Why do you want to copy them? The data is the same.

Comment: What is special about those rows or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Hi, I want to separate these rows in a separated table.

Comment: The rows have pattern like this 3, 7, 11,..., n, n + 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in J3 and copy over enough columns and down enough rows:

```
=INDEX(A:A,((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)+3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, expert. I will study the function. I tried to use OFFSET function today but it couldn't make it work.

Comment: @user3126592 I avoid the OFFSET and INDIRECT as often as possible as they are volatile functions, in that they recalculate every time excel recalcs regardless if the data to which it refers changed or not.  If you have a sheet full of them it will impact the calculation times.